# Can someone please help me understand the params and sign requirement of this legacy rarible mint function? (ERC-721)

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-721, nft, signature

Below is a mint function from a legacy Rarible ERC-721 smart contract:

```
    function mint(uint256 tokenId, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s, Fee[] memory _fees, string memory tokenURI) public {
    require(owner() == ecrecover(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(this, tokenId)), v, r, s), "owner should sign tokenId");
    _mint(msg.sender, tokenId, _fees);
    _setTokenURI(tokenId, tokenURI);
}
```

Firstly, why would a mint function take a tokenId as a parameter? Surely this function would RETURN a tokenId instead...

Secondly (most importantly), why is there a requirement for the owner (contract or token owner?) to match a previous signature. Where does this signature come from and why is it required if ANYONE can mint a token?

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard way to generate tokenIds, developers have ample freedom to create them.

The signature requirements implies that only the owner's key can be used to authorize a new tokenId. Once a tokenId was signed then any account can mint that tokenId.